# Executing subprocess cannot find specified file on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, jython-2.5

I'm working inside a system that has Jython2.5 but I need to be able to call some of Google's apis so I wrote an offline script that I wanted to call from my Jython environment and return to me small pieces of data. Like a JobID or a sheet URL or something from Google.

I've tried a number of things but I always get an error back from Windows, saying that it cannot find the file specified.

Path is done in two ways.

The first way using a string

```
stringPath = r"‪C:\GooglePipes\Scripts\filetobq.py C:\GooglePipes\Keys\DEV-BigQueryKey.json nofile C:\GooglePipes\BQ_Downtime\TESTFILE.CSV dataset1 table1"
```

And the second way, as a sequence (per the docs, using `shell=false` supply a sequence)

```
seqPath = [r"‪C:\GooglePipes\Scripts\filetobq.py",r"C:\GooglePipes\Keys\DEV-BigQueryKey.json","nofile",r"C:\GooglePipes\BQ_Downtime\TESTFILE.CSV","dataset1","table1"]
```

Called with

```
data, err = Popen(seqPath, shell=True, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE).communicate()


#Read values back in
print data
print err
```

Replacing `seqPath` with `stringPath` to try it either way.

I've been at this all weekend, every time I run it I get from Windows

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

from the `err` print. I've been unable to debug much further than this. I'm not really sure what's happening. When I paste the `stringPath` variable directly into my computer's command window it executes.

I've also called `subprocess.list2cmdline(seqPath)` to see what it's outputting. It's giving me a ? in front of the string, but I haven't been able to figure out what that means. I can paste the rest of the string, starting after the question mark into the command window and it executes.

```
?C:\GooglePipes\Scripts\filetobq.py C:\GooglePipes...
```

I've tried a number of different combinations of true and false on shell, passing different args into `Popen`, double slashes, and I have no less than 30 tabs open from stack overflow and other help forums. I just have no idea what to do at this point and any help is appreciated.

### Edit

The ? at the start of the sting is actually a NULL character when I did some additional logging. This seems to be the root of my problem. I can't figure out why it shows up, but it was present in my copy pastes. I started manually typing, and I got it working. When I feed the path with my Jython program it is present again.

Comment: `shell=False` is quite wrong with a single string having multiple arguments (on UNIX; Windows has its own rules) -- the shell is what does the work of splitting the string into the list of argv elements passed to the OS `execv`-family syscall.

Comment: Similarly, *on UNIX*, you *must not* use `shell=True` when passing a multi-element list unless the first element of that list is a shell script and the remaining elements are arguments to that script. But this is all just an informational aside, since that's not your actual platform at hand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Why would it being a shell script matter (so long as it had a shebang)?

Comment: @DavisHerring, with `subprocess.Popen([arg1, arg2, ...], shell=True)` on UNIX, `arg1` isn't expected to be *the name of* a shell script, but *the actual inline text* of a shell script itself. It expands to `['sh', '-c', arg1, arg2, ...]`, and `sh` requires the argument directly following `-c` to be script text to be executed. (In the context of that execution, arg2 becomes `$0`, the argument following it becomes `$1`, etc).

Comment: @DavisHerring, ...if you don't follow that rule, your further arguments are going to simply disappear without being honored: Consider `subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/tmp'], shell=True)`; `/tmp` is passed in `$0`, but the shell script `ls` doesn't inspect `$0`, so the program `ls` that gets run is never passed the `/tmp` argument.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I went back to the docs and I did have it backwards, edited post. Also - sorry to the Unix folks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Ah, of course—I had forgotten about that `subprocess` feature (mostly because I avoid invoking the shell as much as possible).  Thanks for explaining this off-topic point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the error was the ?/NULL character.

I went back to the source value where the program was grabbing the path and it was present there. After I hand-re keyed it in, everything started working.

If you copy and paste what I put in the question, you can see the NULL character in the string if you run it through a string->ASCII converter.

```
>C:
>NULL 67 58
```

What a bunch of bullsh***.